# Neo4j visualizing and retrieving data

Tags: java, maven, neo4j

Starting to use Neo4j embedded with my JAVA web server. While saving the data the transaction was successful, but not able to visualize the data via browser.

Have tried sample Hello world from [tutorial](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/tutorials-java-embedded-hello-world.html). And installed neo4j community edition, after pointing to DB and navigating to http://localhost:7474/browser/ i don't see any data.

Also, when i stop the application and run Cypher query via Java not getting any data.

Maven dependency used

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>neo4j</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Sample code written

```
try {
   Transaction tx = graphDb.beginTx();
   firstNode = graphDb.createNode();
   firstNode.setProperty( "message", "Hello, " );
   secondNode = graphDb.createNode();
   secondNode.setProperty( "message", "World!" );

   relationship = firstNode.createRelationshipTo( secondNode,     RelTypes.KNOWS );
   relationship.setProperty( "message", "brave Neo4j " );
   tx.success();
}
```

DB path for embedded as well as server is same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know exact root of the issue. But I have checklist, that should be verified.

1) You application and Neo4j server should use same database. When you are creating embdedded database via `GraphDatabaseFactory` you are specifying database location. Same database location should be specified for Neo4j server in `conf/neo4j-server.properties` file (`org.neo4j.server.database.location` option).

2) You should **NOT** use database simultaneously in server and application. Database can be used only by one Neo4j instance at a time.

3) Use `try-with-resource` syntax for transactions. It is available in Java7 and later. Example:

```
try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
    // do stuff 
    tx.success();
}
```

In this way transaction will be always closed, in any case (even if exception occurs during execution, or in `beginTx()`).

4) Ensure that your database is closed in “clean way”. In application it can be done via `db.shutdown()` method. Server can be stopped via `bin/neo4j stop`.

Comment: If you are using a try-with-resource syntax, do you still need to close the transaction in a `finally` clause?

Comment: @Supamiu nope. Transaction is closed "automatically". That the whole point of `try-with-resource` syntax. It closes resource when try block is ended. Basically, under the hood, it generates `finally` block that for you, with all necessary checks.

Comment: @FylmTM Changing to try-with-resource have solved the problem. Would be really happy to know the intrinsic of it. No exception happened earlier but moving to try-with-resource worked.

Comment: @Itachi It's hard to tell what is going on without checking full source before and after change. Usually it's about some weird misuse of API.